# Fritzbox modem/router in router-only setup connected to pfsense router works but doesn't show up in DHCP table

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, fritzbox

I have a spare Fritzbox modem/router. This is an old model from my provider that I keep as a backup. I wanted to see if this could work as router only, so I've connected one of the LAN ports to my current pfsense router.

It turned out to work, in the sense that I could connect to the wifi, and I had internet access. If I logon to pfsense, I don't see any IP for the Fritzbox. My laptop gets an IP from pfsense, so it seems like the Fritzbox is acting like an AP only.

I would have thought that it would act like a router with its own network. Why does it work like this, or is this a matter of setup?

Comment: If you want a separate network, connect to the WAN port of the fritzbox.

Comment: @JohnStoneman, see the discussion in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LAN ports on the Fritzbox are acting as a switch which are bridged to the Wireless network, which means that traffic can flow from devices connected, but the Fritzbox itself does not need an IP, which is why you are not seeing it in pfSense.

Comment: This is a modem. It doesn't have a WAN port. It has four LAN ports, one DSL/TEL port, and four FON ports (for Phone, not the Fon service). When I connect to the DSL port, the LED keeps on blinking, the router doesn't show up in pfsense, and internet doesn't work.

Comment: @SPRBRN the first part of the answer still applies, its likely a modem with an embedded router where the WAN part of the router is hard wired to the DSL connection.

Comment: But this means I cannot connect to the interface anymore. If I disconnect the Fritzbox from the pfsense, so it stands on its own, I cannot connect to the Wifi and there is no network. But still the old passwork and networkname are there. It should be able to configure that, doesn't it?

Comment: Ahh... so the real question is, how do you log into the management interface to configure the Fritzbox if it doesn't get an IP from pfSense.  The answer there is that the router does still have an IP address, it is just a static IP, hopefully on a different subnet than the pfSense machine.  To access the management interface you would need to configure your computer with a static IP on the same subnet and then type in the router's IP into your web browser.  If you dont' know the current IP configuration of the router you may need to reset to the default configuraton.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. The default network for Fritzbox routers is 192.168.178.x with the router itself on 1. But this answers my question in even another way! ;-) I wanted to see if I could use this instead of buying a new router for the network of the (small) business of a friend. You just told me that this is complicated to configure (and confusing if someone else is going to support this), so I'm going to advice to buy a new router.

Comment: @SPRBRN, yeah, unless they'll be using the DSL connection, this particular model wont' work for your friend.